# program that solves the classic Sleeping barber problem using pthread

Tags: c, pthreads, race-condition

I tried to solve the [Sleeping Barber problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_barber_problem) using the pthread functions.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define NR_CUSTOMERS 20
#define NR_CHAIRS 3 //chairs in the waiting room + barber chair
sem_t lock;
sem_t customer;
sem_t barber;
int waitingCustomers = 0;
int barberChair = 0;

void *th_customer(void *arg)
{
    int myId = (int)(size_t)arg;
    int tooBusy = 0;

    usleep(1000 * (rand() % 20));
    printf("[C%02d] Entering the barber shop\n", myId);

    sem_wait(&lock);
    if (waitingCustomers < NR_CHAIRS) //if there are still empty seats, the client waits
    {
        ++waitingCustomers;
        printf("[C%02d] %d customer(s) waiting\n", myId, waitingCustomers);
    }
    else
    {
        tooBusy = 1; //if not the client leaves because it is too crowded
    }
    sem_post(&lock);

    if (tooBusy)
    {
        printf("[C%02d] Too busy, will come back another day.\n", myId);
    }
    else //one of the waiting customers is served
    {
        sem_wait(&customer);

        sem_wait(&lock);
        --waitingCustomers;
        sem_post(&lock);

        barberChair = myId;
        sem_post(&barber);
        printf("[C%02d] being served\n", myId);
        usleep(1000);
    }

    return NULL;
}

void *th_barber()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        sem_post(&customer);
        sem_wait(&barber);
        printf("[B ] Serving customer %d\n", barberChair);
        usleep(1000);
    }
    return NULL;
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    pthread_t tidC[NR_CUSTOMERS], tidB;
    srand(time(NULL));

    sem_init(&lock, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&customer, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&barber, 0, 0);

    pthread_create(&tidB, NULL, th_barber, NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < NR_CUSTOMERS; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&tidC[i], NULL, th_customer, (void *)(size_t)(i + 1));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NR_CUSTOMERS; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(tidC[i], NULL);
    }
    pthread_cancel(tidB);
    pthread_join(tidB, NULL);
    sem_destroy(&lock);
    sem_destroy(&customer);
    sem_destroy(&barber);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem: I'm worried about possible concurrence, not the data, that's correct, but in terms of not using available resources: a customer may not receive a haircut due to the maximum number of customers, but one is already on his way to the barber chair, but does he who enters just not notice that his place has just been vacated?

What other problems can be hidden?